# Having trouble with SQL WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I'm trying to select all the club names that have an average score above 0.5 when playing on home field. It displays "invalid use of aggregate function SQLCODE=-150, ODBC 3 State="42000"". If I remove the WHERE statement then it displays all the average scores correctly. The problem must be in the AVG() function but I have no clue on how to fix the problem.

The code:

```
SELECT clubs.name
FROM games JOIN people ON games.home=people.id, people KEY JOIN clubs
WHERE AVG(home_score/2.0) > 0.5
GROUP BY clubs.name
```

Comment: no it isn't the average it is `, people KEY JOIN clubs`

Answer (score -1):

Your query syntax is wrong. The correct syntax should be -

```
SELECT clubs.name
  FROM games 
  JOIN people ON games.home=people.id
  JOIN clubs ON <your join key between clubs and games or people table>
 GROUP BY clubs.name
HAVING AVG(home_score/2.0) > 0.5
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: with out a joined clubs table how do you want to get the club name, this can not work at all

Comment: @nbk, Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected it now.